# Why web page (gmail inbox) only shows source code?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, gmail, source-code-protection

My Gmail inbox doesn't render, it only shows source code. It opens the page and renders normally with others accounts, or in others browsers, but not with my main account AND on google chrome. I've tried to disable and enable javascript (and other general configs as well) and search for that but there's only answers about how to show source code, but that's the opposite of what I want now).

Chrome version: 89.0.4389.114 (oficial) 64 bits
OS: Linux Ubuntu 20.04

More context: Yesterday I was dealing with an issue with CORS, I've tried to install an extension [Moesif Orign & CORS Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc), but latter I disabled it and uninstalled it. I've also associated my main account with Heroku and Swagger if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 11):

You can reload web page(s) and bypass the cache to refresh possibly outdated or corrupted files.

Hold down the Shift key and left-click the Reload button.

> Press "Ctrl + F5" or press "Ctrl + Shift + R" (Windows, Linux)

> Press "Command + Shift + R" (Mac)